# Can someone code and explain the merge portion of mergesort?

Tags: java, algorithm

Ive been trying to understand the merge portion of mergesort for a few hours now, and Ive looked at a bunch of tutorials and walkthroughs. And im not understanding the merge part of mergesort. Theoretically, I understand it. But trying to implement it through code is where Im having a hard time. It's not like I dont understand any of the merge portion of it. I get why you need a couple pointers to keep track of the indices and the reasoning behind the conditional statement in the while loop. But after that I get stuck. I wrote a comment in the merge method on where im stuck. If anyone could just explain to me what I need to code in Java and the reasoning behind it, it'd be great.

EDIT: Added two new while loops the the merge method. All thats left I think for me to do is how to copy the sorted partitions into the `input` array. I think after that it should be working fine... hopefully.

EDIT2: Nevermind the above, I just saw that its not sorting it correctly. Hopefully someone can just modify my code and explain there process

````
    public static void merge(int[] input, int start, int mid, int end) {
        if (input[mid - 1] <= input[mid]) {
            return;
        }
        int i = start;
        int j = mid;
        int tempIndex = 0;

        int[] temp = new int[end - start];
        
        //If i is greater than mid or j is greater than end, that means that half of the array is sorted
        while (i < mid && j < end) {
            temp[tempIndex++] = input[i] <= input[j] ? input[i++] : input[j++];
        }
        //added the two loops below
        while(i < mid){
            temp[tempIndex++] = input[i++];
        }
        while(j < end){
            temp[tempIndex++] = input[j++];
        }
        
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Hint Check if `tempIndex < temp.length`, then continue to fill the array

Comment: Mergesort 'splits' an array in two parts, and then sorts each part individually. Merging checks from which part to take the next item `input[i] <= input[j]`. If it's from the first part, take it and increase counter `input[i++]`, else take from second part `input[j++]`. This is a fast and easy way to merge the two sorted arrays into one sorted array.

Comment: I understand that part, the problem is after the while loop breaks I don't know how to make the remaining numbers merge with the sorted array. I did something like ```while(i < mid) temp[tempIndex++] = input[i++]``` but it didnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

MergeSort is a divide and conquor strategy.

Let's say you have 8 elements.

- The 8 elements get split into 4 elements each (left/right) and mergeSort is invoked on each of them.  We'll ignore merge for now and delve deeper.
- The 4 elements are further split into 2 elements each, and mergeSort is invoked on the 2 element array.
- The 2 elements are further split into 1 elements each, and mergeSort is invoked on each of these at which time, it returns without doing anything.
- So we are finally at the first invocation of merge.  So what does merge do?  Merge joins 2 SORTED lists.  When they are 1 element each, it's just a matter of picking one over the other.  So lets skip forward to the 4 elements and provide an example below:

By the time the 4 element sub-list invokes merge, it may have the following:

```
1 3 2 4
```

Each sub-array (1, 3) and (2, 4) are already sorted by the previous merge.  So we now need to sort the array while merging them like this (I will use a separate output array to demonstrate what should be happening but it can be done in place):

```
for (int i = 0, j = 2, k = 0; k < 4; k++)
{
    int idx;
    if ((j >= 4) || (i < 2 && inputArray[i] < inputArray[j]))
    {
        idx = i++;
    }
    else // j < 4 && (i > 2 || inputArray[j] < inputArray[i])
    {
        idx = j++;
    }
    outputArray[k] = inputArray[idx];
}
```

As you can see, initially we have i pointing to 1, j pointing to 2.  Because 1 < 2, i is selected, and the 1 is output.  Because i was selected, i gets incremented.  Now, we have i pointing to 3 and j pointing to 2.  Because 2 < 3, j gets selected... and so on until we run out of elements.

And after the merge, it will get called on the larger array with 2 4-element sides, repeating the above.

Below is the generalized code without hard coding

```
        public void Merge(int[] input, int start, int mid, int end)
        {
            if (input[mid - 1] <= input[mid])
            {
            }
            else
            {
                int[] tmp = new int[end - start];
                for (int i = start, j = mid, k = 0; k < tmp.Length; k++)
                {
                    int idx;
                    if ((j >= end) || (i < mid && input[i] < input[j]))
                    {
                        idx = i++;
                    }
                    else // j < end && (i > mid || inputArray[j] < inputArray[i])
                    {
                        idx = j++;
                    }
                    tmp[k] = input[idx];
                }

                for (int i = start, j = 0; i < end; i++, j++)
                {
                    input[i] = tmp[j];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I having a little trouble understanding your method. Are the values in the for loop supposed to represent the start, mid, and end of the array?

Comment: Yes, I hard coded to map to the example: 0 is start, 2 is mid, 4 is end, k is tmpIndex and outputArray is tmpArray in your code.  Once this loop is done, tmpArray will be sorted and populated - meaning it must be copied back to the main array - i.e. (for int i = 0, j = start; i < tmpArray.length; i++, j++) inputArray[j] = tmpArray[i];

Comment: Do you think you can let me know whats going wrong in my code? I updated it thinking I had almost fixed it but its still not sorting the partitions correctly.

Comment: You have 3 loops that does god knows what... You should have only 1 main loop to fill the temporary array and then 1 loop to copy the sorted values back to the main array.  See my generalized revision of merge.